# Is there a way to convert Scala-Spark DataFrame to HTML table, or converting DataFrame to Scala map then convert to Json and then HTML?

Tags: html, json, scala, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I run some test and get result which is small DataFrame, with approx 3-6 columns and 10-20 row. And now I want to send this email to my colleague, and for ease I want this to be in tabular format as DataFrame rather then scala map of Json.

So, I want to convert the DataFrame to HTML table which I can attach in email.(This will be done automatically after automated task run of DataBricks)

Till now I have tried converting the DataFrame to Scala map then convert map to Json. but couldn't find anything to convert json to HTML in Scala.

I am converting df to map with this code:

```
val DataFrameToArray = df.collect.map(r => Map(df.columns.zip(r.toSeq):_*))
```

Which gives result as array map below(Sorry forgot to mention that):

```
DataFrameToArray: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]] = Array(map(Name -> Ross, Age -> 31, Gender -> Male), map(Name -> Monica, Age -> 28, Gender -> Female), map(Name -> Joey, Age -> 32, Gender -> Male), map(Name -> Rach, Age -> 29, Gender -> Female))
```

and now I am converting this to array with below code:

```
val newJson = compactRender(decompose(DataFrameToArray))
```

Which gives results as:

```
newJson: String = [{"Name":"Ross","Age":31,"Gender":"Male"},{"Name":"Monica","Age":28,"Gender":"Female"},{"Name":"Joey","Age":32,"Gender":"Male"},{"Name":"Rach","Age":29,"Gender":"Female"}]
```

so it is quite not possibe for me to add it with User case class, or if you can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just write the **HTML** output from your `Map` directly.

```
val records: Array[Map[String, Any]] = Array(
  Map("Name" -> "Ross", "Age" -> 31, "Gender" -> "Male"),
  Map("Name" -> "Monica", "Age" -> 28, "Gender" -> "Female"),
  Map("Name" -> "Joey", "Age" -> 32, "Gender" -> "Male"),
  Map("Name" -> "Rach", "Age" -> 29, "Gender" -> "Female")
)

val htmlTable: String =
  records.map { map =>
    s"<tr><td>${map("Name")}</td><td>${map("Age")}</td><td>${map("Gender")}</td></tr>"
  }.mkString(
    "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Gender</th></tr>",
    "",
    "</table>")
```

---

Other option is to turn your `DataFrame` into a `Dataset[User]`.

```
final case class User (name: String, age: Int, gender: String)

val records: Array[User] = df.as[User].collect()

val htmlTable: String =
      records.map {
        case User(name, age, gender)
          s"<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${age}</td><td>${gender}</td></tr>"
      }.mkString(
        "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Gender</th></tr>",
        "",
        "</table>")
```

Comment: Thanks it can come handy but I am converting df so I don't have user class. if you can help me with that. Comment was too long so I have updated question with specifics.